# A limit point of a set intersects the set in infinite points -- countable or uncountable or depends?

Tags: general-topology

The following theorem in Rudin says:

> If p is a limit points of a set E, then every neighborhood of p contains infinitely many points of E.

My question is, can we go as far as to say that the neighborhood contains an uncountably infinite number of points?

Defining x to be a limit point of the set E. 
Take the open ball, B = { p | d(x,p) < 1 }

Then we have our starting distance value of 1. We then take each value in the interval [0,1] and take a smaller open ball around x that must intersect E (so 1, .99999, ... 0 ). Each new ball we pick a unique unchosen point in the open ball, using the fact that x is a limit point to guarantee we can find a point in E. Hence each point from E is associated with a point in the uncountable interval in [0,1] (namely the distance value that produced our choice of that point).

I believe the above to be wrong, even if a better "starting value" instead of 1 is chosen (for instance a starting value that doesn't completely cover the set E). I'm thinking this is due to this mapping i've defined is not how uncountable sets are defined.

I'm hoping someone can point out why the above is incorrect.

Thanks!

Comment: What if your metric space were countable? Also, you may wish to have a look at exercise 27 in Ch 2.

Comment: Take $E=\{1/n\}$. Then $0$ is the only limit point of $E$ . Also every nbd of $0$ contains infinitely not uncountably many points of $E$.

Comment: so in my above construction, when I start looking for unique points at each interval, I will eventually run out in the E = {1/n} example. But the points I've picked when I run out will end up being infinite and sufficiently clustered near my limit point

Comment: Caution: Different authors may have differing definitions of " limit point ". Whenever starting a  new book, spend some time learning the author's definitions.

Comment: here it would be every open set around x intersects E in a point other than itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Each new ball we pick a unique *unchosen* point"

Yes, the problem is that no such "unchosen" point may exist! For example, considering the set $E =  \{\frac 1n : n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}$. Pick an uncountable set $S \subset [0,1]$. Suppose that for each $ \epsilon \in S$, there is a unique point $x_\epsilon \in E$  such that $x_\epsilon$ belongs to $B(0,\epsilon)$ but not to any $B(0,\delta)$ for $\delta < \epsilon, \delta \in S$. Then, the above association provides a $1-1$ map from $S \to E$, given by mapping $\epsilon$ to the point $x_\epsilon$.This contradicts the fact that $E$ is countable.

Therefore, at least existentially, we can show  that this map is not injective. In other words, after some time, you will definitely run out of points to choose  for a given $\epsilon$, and will have to choose another point.

(Please use whatever definition of limit point you have to verify that $0$ is a limit point of $E$ as well)

Also, try to think about conditions which you can impose so that indeed any such neighbourhood will contain uncountably many points. Do you think an interior point (which is also a limit point) will have this property (in $\mathbb R$)?

Comment: wouldnt any x in B(0,e) also be a member of B(0,delta) for delta > e?

Comment: The sign should be the other way.

Comment: are u saying for an interior point x in V, take the open set U containing x such that U is contained within the open set V and stating that U could be uncountable? in general this won't be true, but in R since the open intervals are (a,b), and are uncountable themsevles, any point in the interior would satisfy ur epsilon delta condition for a 1-1 mapping. do u agree?

Comment: Exactly. Therefore, on the real line(and $\mathbb R^n$ by extension) at least you may be able to place conditions on a limit point so that every neighbourhood of it intersects the set at uncountably many points.

Comment: (specifically each epsilon we pick will return a unique x we can choose as we map to the uncountable interval )

Comment: Yes. So for example if $E$ is a set, fix a limit point of $E$ which is also an interior point of $E$, say $x$. Now, $B(x,\delta) \subset E$. Fix $y$ in this ball, with say $B(y,x) = \delta'$, and consider the line segment joining $x$ and $y$. Now, for any $\epsilon < \delta'$, the ball around $x$ of radius $\epsilon$ will always contain some part of this line segment, and a line segment has uncountably many points if its endpoints are different.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark but: I arrived at this question via the theorem that in a connected metric space X with more than point, the space must be uncountable. i found the proof of that to be quite interesting and just thought I'd ask if you know of any similar proofs (in general topology or analysis) using a continuous function to map to a different space as a proof technique. the proof can be found here: https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-3/section-27-compact-subspaces-of-the-real-line/problem-4-solution/

Comment: Very interesting proof! I actually don't recall immediately any such proof, unfortunately, but that's why I must thank you for showing me the above result, for I did not know about it.